# No documents returned when I want to display them from my JS file

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When I try Mycollection.find().count() in the console of the browser I get the real number of documents. But when I want to display it from my app.js file:

```
Mycollection = new Mongo.Collection('mycollection');
Template.body.rendered = function () {
var mycollectionCursor = Mycollection.find();
if (mycollectionCursor.count()){
console.log(mycollectionCursor.count());
}else{
console.log("********");
};
```

I get ******* in my browser, I want to manipulate my documents. What have I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the subscription handle

```
let handle = Meteor.subscribe(//name of subscription)
```

Now inside the tracker check if subscription is ready inside the rendered function

```
Tracker.autorun(function(c){
   if(handle.ready()){
     console.log(MyCollection.find().count())
     c.stop()
   }
})
```

Hope it helps

Thanks

Comment: Yes :) it helps me. Thank you Khem ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish your data and subscribe to it in your client. If you did not remove "autopublish" yet, all what you have will automatically be published. So when you query a collection on client (in a helper method for example), you would get results. This package is useful just for quick development and prototyping, but in a real application it should be removed. You should publish your data according to your app's needs and use cases. (Not all users have to see all data in all use cases)

Comment: I removed autopublish and I am using publish/subscribe from the beginning. I think the pb is not there. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the line:

```
if (mycollectionCursor.count()){
```

`count()` will return an `int` rather than a `boolean`.  You need to check if the count is greater than 0, which will indicate that the cursor has documents.  For example:

```
if (mycollectionCursor.count() > 0){
```

or try replacing it with:

```
if (Mycollection.count() > 0){
```

Comment: if (mycollectionCursor.count()) and if (mycollectionCursor.count() > 0) are the same :)

Comment: have you tried moving console.log(mycollectionCursor.count()) outwith the if?

Comment: Yes, and it gives to me 0 :(

Comment: PB is in function find(), it returns null cursor !!

Comment: Do you expect there to be documents returned?  Are there documents in the collection?  Have you tried  console.log(Mycollection.count())

Comment: Yes I am sure there are documents in my collection ! I tried "db.mycollection.find() " in my terminal ( meteor mongo) and "Screens.find().fetch();" in browser console :(